# sort by score and date in elasticsearch

Tags: sorting, elasticsearch

i need get searched result sorted by _score and date field
i use below query in php elasticseach and get result true by _score , but i need sort data with _score and date field

Array([index] => my_index [from] => 0 [size] => 20 [body] => Array ( [query] => Array ( [bool] => Array ( [must] => Array ( [0] => Array ( [multi_match] => Array ( [query] => i need find it [operator] => or [fields] => Array ( [0] => src ) [lenient] => 1 ) ) ) ) ) ) [sort] => Array([0] => _score:desc))

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add one more field in sort array. Below is example of Elasticsearch query:

```json
{
    "sort": [
        {
            "_score": "desc"
        },
        {
            "date": {
                "order": "asc",
                "format": "strict_date_optional_time_nanos"
            }
        }
    ],
    "query": {
        "term": {
            "user": "kimchy"
        }
    }
}
```

**PHP Example**

```php
'sort' => array(
            array("_score" => "desc"),
            array("date" => "asc")
        )
```